# How Can restricting access to MS SQL Server 2008 only to local IPs and users?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, server, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I installed MS SQL server 2008 on windows server 2008, my server is connected to the internet and I need to restrict access to ms SQL server so that only local users and IPs in my network can access to it not public IPs and people from outside of my network(via internet) could not access to it, how can I do that?

Comment: Just two words - Windows firewall.

Comment: can you explain it step by step? @MarekVitek

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since I don't know your firewall settings. But since your server is connected to internet there should be some restrictions already in place. In case they are not, then open Windows Firewall and create Inbound rule for port 1433 TCP and on Scope tab put in Local IP address IP address of your interface to the internet. Same for port 1434 UDP.

Comment: These links might come handy [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port) and [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access) Except you would be doing oposite. Also are you sure that your server is accessible from outside? Have you checked it?

Comment: Also how many network interfaces your server has? Is it one for local network and one for internet? Or is your server placed in DMZ?